# Display animating view within ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, dry, viewcontroller

EDITED:

I had created a slide in menu for my view and it works as i wanted, this was the original guide that I used.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79ZQDzzOHLk

My goal was to get this programmed once in a class and get it to work on any view controller that i decided to call it in.

Thanks to @harsh.prasad and some additional research I have managed to get this to work to a point where it works as I want apart apart from linking buttons on to it.

So to update this question in the hope it may help someone else.

This is what I did:

I created a UIView class and called it MenuOne.

MenuOne.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TFMenuOne : UIView {
    // Pop Up Menu

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *openMenu;
    int draw1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
}

// Pop Up Menu
- (IBAction)openMenu_clicked:(id)sender;

// Reset draw1 to 0
- (void) resetView: (id) sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

MenuOne.m

```
#import "TFMenuOne.h"

@implementation TFMenuOne
@synthesize scrollView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        draw1 = 0;

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 315, 568, 5)];
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(568, 5)];


        backButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [backButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(224, 350, 120, 30);

        openMenu = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [openMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-button-@2.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        openMenu.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
        [openMenu addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(openMenu_clicked:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(256, 269, 64, 46);


        [self addSubview:scrollView];
        [self addSubview:backButton];
        [self addSubview:openMenu];

    } 
    return self; 
}

// Allow for touch even through transparent View class
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (!view.hidden && view.userInteractionEnabled && [view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void) resetView: (id) sender {
    draw1 = 1;
    [self openMenu_clicked:sender];
}

- (IBAction)openMenu_clicked:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 == 0) {

        draw1 = 1;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 260, 568, 60);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(256, 214, 64, 46);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            backButton.frame = CGRectMake(224, 275, 120, 30);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];


    } else {

        draw1 = 0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 315, 568, 5);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(256, 269, 64, 46);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            backButton.frame = CGRectMake(224, 350, 120, 30);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

    }
}


/* 
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing. 
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation. 
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
 { 
 // Drawing code 
 } 
 */ 

@end
```

After a lot of trial and error, in order to get this UIView class to appear on multiple ViewControllers I call the view like this in the m file of the view controller. The obstacles I ran in to was that the menu would open but when I left the view controller to go to another view controller the menu would be in the state it was in when i left, it wouldn't reset back to closed. The code below covered that thanks again to @harsh.prasad. I also managed to get the menu to animate in.

```
@interface TFMapViewController ()
{
    TFMenuOne *menuView;
}

@end

@implementation TFMapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [menuView resetView:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    menuView = [[TFMenuOne alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 51, 568, 320)];
    [self.view addSubview:menuView];

}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}


- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [menuView resetView:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 51, 568, 320);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Allows for Exit button to work
- (IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}


@end
```

Comment: You should definitely look at [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

Comment: Thanks Janak but this is not what I am looking for. I have looked into the slide menu but it gives a different effect to what I want - I want my menu to appear over the view controller and not behind, and i want to be able to add buttons and images on to it not just a text menu. I have already achieved what I want but wanted to know if there is an efficient way to not have to repeat the same code on every view controller. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want you can use tabsController if that kind of feature you want, otherwise create a class of your slide in menu view and then you can use it in all of your views as you like. No same piece of code is to be rewritten.

**EDIT**:
Suppose you have created a class CustomMenuView which basically creates your menu view. So now you can use this in every view controller you want to use it in in the following way:

```
CustomMenuView *menuView = [CustomMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 100);
menuView.<properties you want to pass> = <set properties here>;
[self.view addSubView:menuView];
```

This will set the view with the custom menu and then you can handle the actions in this menu.

Comment: So if I create a class for the menu only do I also create  a view controller for it and if so how do I then call it to each View Controller I want it to appear on?

Comment: Just a UIView class of your menu is sufficient. Just handle the view in initWithFrame function. I think this could solve your problem easily.

Comment: Ok any idea on how I would code this? I have created the class now and it is sitting there but no idea how to code it in to each view controller to get it to work.Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my original answer. You can set the frame according to your needs. This should work

Comment: Hi harsh.prasad, I am learning objective-c and really appreciate your time and effort in helping me but i think you are assuming that I know more than I do. Do I need to import, if so what do i import and why would i want to set properties when I have already done this in the menu view controller? I am just getting errors. The first line says that it is expecting ] and then I just get errors saying that no visible @interface  for initWithFrame. I had tried importing the m and h files and both give same errors - any ideas? PS I put you code in viewDidLoad

Comment: Ohh Kk. First of all, what is the name of your custom menu view? And how are you initialising it? And you only had to import .h files.

Comment: I'll edit my questions and code above now as I can't put it in here

Comment: No need for a view controller just make your interface of type UIView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43568/discussion-between-dan-davies-and-harsh-prasad)

Answer (score 0):

1)Here is an old tutorial for creating menu - http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path/projectlayout

2)A better way is to create Drawer menu With container views. You can read more about container views from WWDC videos.

3)Or if you are lazy to d it yourself, try this library http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtrevealsidebar

P.S. No , you do not havev to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

First make a view on the origin point x = 0 y = 480  (for iphone4) and then run this code.

```
CGRect theFrame = self.viewMenuShare.frame;
theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 480);
self.viewMenuShare.frame = theFrame;
theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,480 - 187);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
self.viewMenuShare.frame = theFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```